# Error handling monads in Scala? Try vs Validation

Tags: validation, scala, error-handling, monads, scalaz

`scalaz.Validation` is said to be more powerful than the `Try` monad, because it can accumulate errors.

Are there any occasions where you might choose `Try` over `scalaz.Validation` or `scalaz.\/`  ?

Comment: There is no `flatMap` in `Validation` and `\/` in not a semantically correct instrument. But it's only my opinion, not an answer to your question.

Comment: What's wrong with `\/`?

Comment: @TravisBrown: [symmetry](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scalaz/Wnkdyhebo2w/3Prv5yslDCsJ). There should be no difference between `left` and `right`. I can't explain to my colleagues why `\/` works the way it works, "there is no logic, just remember it" is not an explanation.

Comment: @mpilquist: Yes, it's not satisfying. There is no reason to give symmetric names (`left/right`) to not symmetric types (`good/bad`).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The most significant argument in favor of `Try` is that it's in the standard library. It's also *used* in the standard library—for example the callbacks you register with `Future`'s `onComplete` must be functions from `Try`. It may be used more extensively in the standard library in the future.

The fact that it's in the standard library also means it'll look familiar to more people. You'll probably tend to find it in more of the third-party libraries you use. And of course sometimes you may not be allowed to use Scalaz (or any other dependencies) or may want to avoid Scalaz for other perfectly good reasons.

Other stuff: I can't remember the last time I wrote a `\/` that didn't have `Throwable` on its left side (I have—it's just not something I do often). `Try` bakes this in, so you don't have to worry about writing an alias or whatever.

As [senia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/406435/senia) notes in the comments above, there's arguably something a little unintuitive about biasing an either-like type but still using the language of "left" and "right" (as `\/` is, and does). Why does `\/` bind through the right side? Because it does, that's why. I personally don't find the naming that objectionable, but I can understand why some people might. `Try` avoids the issue by having constructor names that clearly indicate their semantics: `Success` and `Failure`, not `Left` and `Right` or `-\/` and `\/-`.

Now that we're getting to the completely superficial and subjective reasons to use `Try`, some people may just think `\/` and `-\/` and `\/-` are ugly. I generally don't mind operator-heavy code, and I find the jumble of slashes and dashes really unpleasant to type and read.

So those are some arguments in favor of `Try`, as requested, but I'll conclude by saying that I never use it, myself. I don't specifically care all that much about the fact that it [violates the monad laws](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-debate/K6wv6KphJK0%5B101-125-false%5D) (although I can understand why people do), but I do find `\/` and `Validation` much less ad-hoc and easier to reason about, and I like having access to both (`Validation` [when I want to accumulate errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12309023/334519), `\/` [when I need monadic sequencing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20065853/334519)) in a single framework.

Comment: What is the problem with "left" and "right"?  right == correct.  It's a pun, is that such a confusing thing?  Scalaz confused the issue in removing the pun, that's the problem.

Comment: Ok, this left me confused... `Try` is something that capture exceptions and turn them into values, a specialized `Either[Exception, T]`. `Validation` doesn't seem to handle exceptions in any way, so, to me, they look quite orthogonal to each other.

Comment: The Latin adjective sinister/sinistra/sinistrum originally meant "left" but took on meanings of "evil" or "unlucky" by the Classical Latin era, and this double meaning survives in European derivatives of Latin, and in the English word "sinister". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_against_left-handed_people https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dexter_and_sinister