# Why `scala.util.Try` is not mentioned in chapter "Handling errors without exceptions" of book "functional programming in Scala"?

Tags: scala, exception, either

In the chapter "Handling errors without exceptions" of book "functional programming in Scala", the author gives:

1. The problem of throwing exceptions from the body of a function
2. Use `Option` if we don't care about the actual exception
3. Use `Either` if we care about the actual exception

But `scala.util.Try` is not mentioned. From my point of view, I think `Try` is very suitable when we care about the actual exception, why it's not mentioned? Is there any reason I have missed?

Comment: My guess is that the book was written before Try was added to the Scala standard library. Try was added in version 2.10.

Comment: On page 58 and 61 they implement their own `Try` function using their definitions of resp `Option` and `Either`. _FP in Scala_ is not a book about Scala but about Functional Programming (in Scala), that's why the exercises reimplement parts of the existing Scala API to learn the concept of FP.

Comment: @marstran `Try` has been around since 2012 and the book was published this year. If `Try` was relevant and the authors had wanted to discuss it, they would have.

Comment: @PeterNeyens That's a good thought, but in the book, it mentions that there are built-in `Option` and `Either` in Scala sdk

Comment: When I used Try. I found it tended to become invasive across function/method return types, a bit like checked exceptions in Java, i.e. Try[] just started to appear everywhere, cluttering up the source code. Of course, YMMV.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I'm neither of the authors of Functional Programming in Scala, but I can make a few guesses about why they don't mention `Try`.

Some people don't like the standard library's `Try` because they claim [it violates the functor composition law](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6284). I personally think that this position is kind of silly, for the reasons Josh Suereth mentions in the comments of SI-6284, but the debate does highlight an important aspect of `Try`'s design.

`Try`'s `map` and `flatMap` are explicitly designed to work with functions that may throw exceptions. People from the FPiS school of thought (including me) would tend to suggest wrapping such functions (if you absolutely have to deal with them at all) in safe versions at a low level in your program, and then exposing an API that will never throw (non-fatal) exceptions.

Including `Try` in your API muddles up the layers in this model—you're guaranteeing that your API methods won't throw exceptions, but then you're handing people a type that's designed to be used with functions that throw exceptions.

That's only a complaint about the standard library's design and implementation of `Try`, though. It's easy enough to imagine a version of `Try` with different semantics, where the `map` and `flatMap` methods didn't catch exceptions, and there would still be good reasons to avoid this "improved" version of `Try` whenever possible.

One of these reasons is that using `Either[MyExceptionType, A]` instead of `Try[A]` makes it possible to get more mileage out of the compiler's exhaustivity checking. Suppose I'm using the following simple ADT for errors in my application:

```
sealed class FooAppError(message: String) extends Exception(message)

case class InvalidInput(message: String) extends FooAppError(message)
case class MissingField(fieldName: String) extends FooAppError(
  s"$fieldName field is missing"
)
```

Now I'm trying to decide whether a method that can *only* fail in one of these two ways should return `Either[FooAppError, A]` or `Try[A]`. Choosing `Try[A]` means we're throwing away information that's potentially useful both to human users and to the compiler. Suppose I write a method like this:

```
def doSomething(result: Either[FooAppError, String]) = result match {
  case Right(x) => x
  case Left(MissingField(_)) => "bad"
}
```

I'll get a nice compile-time warning telling me that the match is not exhaustive. If I add a case for the missing error, the warning goes away.

If I had used `Try[String]` instead, I'd also get exhaustivity checking, but the only way to get rid of the warning would be to have a catch-all case—it's just not possible to enumerate all `Throwable`s in the pattern match.

Sometimes we actually can't conveniently limit the kinds of ways an operation can fail to our own failure type (like `FooAppError` above), and in these cases we can always use `Either[Throwable, A]`. Scalaz's `Task`, for example, is essentially a wrapper for `Future[Throwable \/ A]`. The difference is that `Either` (or `\/`) *supports* this kind of signature, while `Try` *requires* it. And it's not always what you want, for reasons like useful exhaustivity checking.

Comment: As a footnote, see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21665747/334519) for some additional discussion.

Comment: Good answer, though I think you seriously undersell the value of `Try` in taming unruly external code.  Wrapping things takes time.  `Try` is awesome when things can break in all sorts of ways but it's still valuable to get an unbroken answer if you can have one.

Comment: @RexKerr Agreed! At my day job we rely heavily on `Try` (our own, but it's essentially the same as the standard library's), and if the alternative is exceptions everywhere `Try` is fantastic. I guess I could make it a little clearer that I'm answering the question "why might some people not like `Try`?", not "should I avoid `Try`?".

Comment: I think catching exceptions in map/flatMap was the right call. Think what would happen if Try would be async - without explicitly catching exceptions, they'd leave no trace, silently killing the thread where they are executed. As it happens Future is async and the equivalent of Try. Without catching the exception in a flatMap, you wouldn't be able to recover from it. And I agree with you that an Either better signals possible errors, but Try is still useful for situations in which you can have unexpected exceptions. And for example I/O operations can lead to unplanned exceptions.

Comment: I also think that catching exceptions in map/flatMap is the right call because people expect "safety" while in Try's context. People expect that because that's why they are using Try in the first place. This is the principle of least astonishment.

Comment: What's the benefit of `extend`-ing `Exception`  in the ADT of `FooAppError`?