# Can I use \/ type of scalaz to accumulate failures?

Tags: scala, error-handling, scalaz

I know that [\/ (disjunction type)](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Either.scala) in scalaz can be used to "fail fast", i.e. return the first failure in a sequence of functions calls. What if I want to "fail slow", i.e. accumulate the failures ? I can use `Validation` of scalaz.

Now I wonder if [\/ (disjunction type)](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Either.scala) provides any built-in support for accumulating failures.

Comment: You can always implement either behavior for either type—the issue is just which you get for free when you sequence through the type's applicative functor.

Comment: @TravisBrown You are right (and I will update the question). I wonder if `\/` provides any _built-in support_ for failures accumulation. It looks like it does since it implements `ap` method ... but I still do not know exactly how to use it.

Comment: `\/`'s applicative functor is fail-fast: if both `x` and `y` fail in `(x |@| y)` you'll only see the error for `x`.

Comment: You might look at `+++` and `\/`'s monoid instance, which offer a kind of failure accumulation, but it's not nearly as flexible as what you get with `Validation`.

Comment: Thank you. I got it :) Now I am thinking when one will use it as a monad and when as a applicative functor.

Comment: For any well-behaved type the applicative and monadic behavior should be consistent—that's why `Validation` is no longer a monad.

Comment: I see. I wonder why `\/` is both a monad and applicative. Should I use it as an applicative _instead of_ using it as a monad (as less powerful abstraction).

Comment: Sometimes you need monadic sequencing—see my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20065853/334519) for some discussion. When you don't need it, sticking with applicative syntax is generally a good policy.

Comment: Thank you. It is clearer now.