# Advantages of using \/ as applicative functor in Scalaz

Tags: scala, error-handling, scalaz

This is a follow-up to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22755577/can-i-use-type-of-scalaz-to-accumulate-failures)

Suppose I have two functions that return `\/` (see below). I need to call both of them and "fail fast".

```
type CheckResult = String \/ Unit

def checkX(): CheckResult = ...
def checkY(): CheckResult = ...
```

Suppose also that those functions can be called in any order. Thus I can use `\/` as an applicative functor rather than a monad.

```
checkX() |@| checkY()
```

Unfortunately I do not understand *exactly* why it is better than a monadic sequencing. Suppose this is a less powerful abstraction. Is there any concrete advantage of using `\/` as an applicative in this specific case ?

Comment: This seems a little like a duplicate of [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19880207/334519), and I think my answer there is relevant (although that depends on what you mean by _concrete_).

Comment: Thanks Travis. It does look like a duplicate :( I probably need to iterate it again and consider monad vs. applicative in different contexts to understand that thing better.